# Integration problem - am I doing this right?

Tags: calculus, integration

I apologize if this is a painfully easy question. This is my second day working with anti-derivatives so I'm pretty new to the whole integration thing. All right then, let's get on with the problem!

We are give the acceleration function of time A(t), two position function results with S(t). Remember that S''(t) = A(t).

---

We are given
$$A(t) = 10\sin(x) + 3\cos(x)$$
And...
$$S(0) = 0$$
$$S(2\pi) = 12$$

---

So the first thing I did was integrate A(t) twice to find S(t). I got this:
$$S(t) = Cx+C-10\sin(x)-3\cos(x)$$

I tried plugging in the S values I know but I keep getting spooky answers. Where to go from here?

Comment: I assume it's a typo that you used $x$ in your definition of $A(t)$ instead of $t$? Ignoring that, you're integrating twice, so you should have two unknown constants. It should be $S(x)=Cx+D-10\sin(x)-3\cos(x)$ where $C,D$ are constants. Now, use the initial conditions to find the values of $C$ and $D$.

Comment: I need two different constants if I integrate twice?

Comment: Yes, because integration gives you a family of curves. The first time you integrate, you get a family of curves differing by a constant. The second time you integrate, you get a family of a family of curves where the curves of each family differ by a constant. So, you require two constants. Also, could you clarify me regarding the typo I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. And thank you, I understand now!